# JavaScript modular framework for a large web-site

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, framework

In my ASP.NET MVC project I simply inserted `<script></script>` into my views - it caused code duplications and spaghetti code.

Now, I have decided to switch to modular JS and have implemented the following mechanism:

- ALL actions are only executed through the framework and its modules - whether it is a view or object behavior, date-to-string converter or websocket connection
- every module exposes `exports` functions, which can be called by anybody, including other modules
- all functions including `exports` and `init` are called within a sandboxed `context`, which includes both objects specific for the module and objects, injected by a framework (currently, I am implementing the mechanism to "hide" / disallow non-context methods within a module)

Framework object with the only `register` function:

```
window.kibfw = {
    register: function(name, module) {
        if (!name || !module.init)
            throw new Error('Could not load a module ' + name);

        if (name === 'register')
            throw new Error('Module cannot have name "register" which is reserved');

        if (this[name])
            throw new Error('Module ' + name + ' is already registered.');

        module.context = module.context || {};

        /* Here, inject the required context objects (jQuery, libraries etc.) */
        module.context.$ = window.jQuery;
        module.context.kibfw = window.kibfw;

        try {
            module.init.apply(module.context, arguments);    
        } catch(e) {
            throw new Error('Error during module initialization: ' + e.message + '\n' + e.stackTrace);
        }

        var moduleExports = (this[name] = {});
        for (var exportFnName in module.exports) {
            if (!module.exports.hasOwnProperty(exportFnName))
                continue;

            moduleExports[exportFnName] = (function (exportFn) {
                return function() {
                    try {
                        exportFn.apply(module.context, arguments);
                    } catch (e) {
                        throw new Error('Module: ' + name + '. Error during method invocation: ' + e.message + '\n' + e.stackTrace);
                    }
                };
            })(module.exports[exportFnName]);
        }
    }
};
```

Example module:

```
kibfw.register('decorator', {
  init: function () {
    this.$decorateItems = this.$('input');
  },
  context: {
    $decorateItems: undefined
  },
  exports: {
    setColor: function (color) {
      this.$decorateItems.css('color', color);
    }
  }
});

// Usage:
$("button").click(function() {
    kibfw.decorator.setColor($(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

**[JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/k32fkgwp/3/)**

How do you think, would it be useful and scalable?
Which problems can I stumble upon while using this approach?

Comment: Question - why not use AMD or a preprocessor like Webpack to achieve this? You're reinventing CommonJS here.

Answer (score 2):

Very readable code, some minor comments:

- Some folks dislike the lacking curly braces for one liners, I dont mind it here myself
- JsHint will complain about you creating a function in a `for` loop, I think you should indeed refactor that
- Using `this[name]` to register modules would be to fickle for me (shenanigans with `bind`, `apply`, and `call` come to mind), I would prefer a self executing function with a `var` statement.
- You only have 1 line of comment, for a very straightforward piece of code, I would have commented the `moduleExports[exportFnName] = (function (exportFn) {` line
- I would split this out in to 2 different error messages:  `if (!name || !module.init)
          throw new Error('Could not load a module ' + name);`
- Actually, in your code I see that `init` is a bit contrived, I would not make that mandatory personally

Now, when I take a step back, I think you might be suffering from Second System Syndrome. Consider that in effect you are replacing

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('input').attr('data-color'));
});
```

with

```
kibfw.register('decorator', {
  init: function () {
    this.$decorateItems = this.$('input');
  },
  context: {
    $decorateItems: undefined
  },
  exports: {
    setColor: function (color) {
      this.$decorateItems.css('color', color);
    }
  }
});

// Usage:
$("button").click(function() {
    kibfw.decorator.setColor($(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

I like `window.kibfw`, it is pretty beautiful. But I would hate to have to write a website with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Very useful answer, I will accept this one. I have come up with a simple solution, which I will show in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

After konijn's feedback, I have come up with a simpler solution

Module framework:

```
var Module = (function() {
  function module(name, constructor) {
    if (module[name]) {
      throw new Error('Module ' + name + ' already exists.');
    }

    var exports = (module[name] = {});
    constructor.call(null, exports);
  } 

  return module;
})();
```

New module declaration (`new` keyword doesn't have any practical usage, just for readbility):

```
new Module('decorator', function(exports) {
  var $decorateItems = $("p"); 

  exports.setColor = function(color) { 
    $decorateItems.css('color', color);
  };
});
```

Calling an exported function:

```
Module.decorator.setColor('blue');
```

After some code analysis, I have understood that all my modules are independent, and only a couple modules will be called from others - I will simply load them first using ASP.NET MVC Bundling.
Modules dependency and requirements features really seem like an overkill here.